# Correct tense with reported speech?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

From a multiple choice question in my English assignment:

> He will probably want to know if you
>
> A. will have been drinking
>   B. didn't drink
>   C. had drunk
>   D. have been drinking

I heard many people said D is the correct answer, but isn't this reported speech so it should be C?

Comment: I don't think it's reported speech as the question has not been asked yet. Other options are possible, but the most likely scenario is that someone is going to be questioned by a doctor or policeman who will need to know if they could be under the influence of alcohol  (so, option D).

Comment: I don't find *any* of the sentences to actually be asyntactic.